# CREATE TRIGGER sys_exec and python

Tags: python, mysql, linux, triggers

my python on /usr/esercizi/ is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
aa = now.strftime("%Y-%d-%m %H:%M | %S")

out_file = open("/usr/esercizi/test.txt","w")
out_file.write("La data di oggi \n\n")
out_file.write(aa)
out_file.close()
```

made for test purpose I like it to be called from a TRIGGER:

```
mysql> CREATE TRIGGER `notifica_cambiamenti` AFTER UPDATE ON `valore`
    -> FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    ->
    -> SET @exec_var = sys_exec(CONCAT('python /usr/esercizi/tre.py ', NEW.valore));
    -> END;
    -> $$
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.06 sec)
```

the table has only two columns: id and valore.
every time  change the valore should run the tre.py

I also  give:

> chown mysql:mysql tre.py  | and chmod 777 tre.py

the Query OK, seems to indicate that there are no syntax errors
but **nothing happens** on the file: test.txt

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: On the command line, what does running `python /usr/esercizi/tre.py 1` output? What does running `mysql -e "SELECT sys_exec('python /usr/esercizi/tre.py 1');"` output?

Comment: thanks for the reply, in the first case it does the job. In the second I have problems with permissions:      <code> mysql -e "SELECT sys_exec('python /usr/esercizi/tre.py 1');"
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'  (using password: NO)</code>

Comment: What does running `mysql -h hostname -u root -ppassword -e "SELECT sys_exec('python /usr/esercizi/tre.py 1');"` output?

Comment: What directory do you expect test.txt to appear in?

Comment: I just  changed as suggested: out_file = open("/usr/esercizi/test.txt","w")  but nothing happens??

Comment: @Ross Smith       <br>                                                   +-------------------------------------------+<br>
| sys_exec('python /usr/esercizi/tre.py 1') |<br>
+-------------------------------------------+<br>
|                                        -1 |<br>
+-------------------------------------------+<br>

Comment: The the `sys_exec()` function is returning `-1`, which probably indicates an error. Perhaps the `python` executable is not in the path for the mysql daemon. Type `whereis python` to find out the directory is installed in, and then try: `mysql -h hostname -u root -ppassword -e "SELECT sys_exec('/path/to/python /usr/esercizi/tre.py 1');"` after you change `/path/to/` to the path returned by `whereis`.

Comment: +-----------------------------------------------------+
| sys_exec('/usr/bin/python  /usr/esercizi/tre.py 1') |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
|                                                  -1 |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
is returning -1

Comment: @andry88 Why do you need this at all? It's RDBMS so populate a **log table** instead of a file. And if you need any further processing use a cron job or mysql event to do so.

Comment: HI. Do you think a demon with cron is more efficient than controlling a process by TRIGGER? is an interesting talk on efficiency

Comment: @andry88 I think that writing to a table is much faster than calling non-native extension (sys_exec) that forks external process that writes to a file especially from a trigger in a middle of an update with locks and everything.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is solved,just do the following which I did for your problem...

```
CREATE TABLE log_table( datetime update_time, varchar() valore);
```

I just created the above table where the updated values will be stored by the trigger.

Now,I defined the trigger as follows..

```
  DELIMITER ;;

  CREATE TRIGGER `notifica_cambiamenti` AFTER UPDATE ON `valore`

  FOR EACH ROW

     BEGIN

       INSERT INTO log_table

          SET update_time = NOW(),
              valore      = NEW.valore);

   END;;
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are proposing has severe performance problems. (Imagine someone does a bulk insert of 1000's of rows -- it will create 1000's of python processes and quickly bring your server down.) Here is a much simpler way without the problems: (WARNING: untested pseudo code)

```
CREATE TABLE log_table( datetime update_time, varchar() valore);

CREATE TRIGGER `notifica_cambiamenti` AFTER UPDATE ON `valore`
-> FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
->
-> insert into log_table(now(), NEW.valore);
-> END;
-> $$
```

Now, you can make an async job (or cron job) that periodically processes the log table and deletes the rows it has seen:  `DELETE FROM log_table WHERE update_time < $LAST_ROW_SEEN`.

Advanced note: This will work fine until you need to process many jobs per second, or reduce latency without polling the database 100's of times per second. In that case, you shouldn't use an SQL database. Use a real queue like AMPQ, Redis/Resque, Celery, etc. The client will insert the the row into SQL, then also throw the job into the job queue. You can have many workers processing jobs in parallel.